# Curved fishnet (vector grid for extraction) in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, vector-grid

I am trying to create a sampling grid for a raster data set. I am using ArcGIS Desktop 10.5.1. with an Advanced License on a Windows 10, 64 bit.

The raster data set shows tractor tramlines in crop fields from north to south. I would like to establish a grid along the these tractor lines that splits the whole field into 10m (n-s direction) sections. The width is dependent on the tramlines, which varies.
On most examples these tractor lines are nicely straight, but in one example they are slightly curved (put still parallel) because the field is shaped like a half circle around a forest (that is not unusual in Europe).

I will need this vector grid file later to extract information from the raster. I need to do a majority vote inside each cell of the grid.

I have tried using fishnet grid, but I have only been successful with the perfect straight lines. This approach is not helpful with the curved lines.
Is there a method with which I can make bent fishnets?

I have further tried to create polygons around the lines using a simple buffer. Now this buffer needed to be split in intervals of 10 m. As far as I have researched, there are options in Arc Pro with Divide and Subdivide polygons (as shown [here](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/subdivide-polygon.htm) and [here](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/editing/divide-a-polygon-by-a-value.htm) ) - but I have not been able to find that in ArcGIS Desktop 10.5.1.
I have also researched, that for some specific cases, a method using split parcels would work out, however parcel processing is lagging severly on this machine and it also requires to re-draw and connect all the polygons. Therefore, I am looking for another option!

Is there any tool that would split curved polygons in intervals and preferably in an automated way? Or Something that inserts e.g. a perpendicular line every 10m and could be merged to a grid later?

(edited to clarify)

Comment: Create Fishnet is only for rectangular tessellations. While you could certainly generate your own geometries via coordinate math and an insert cursor, that's not a function of Create Fishnet.

Comment: Thanks for your advice!
 I will try with another technique then.