# Dividing a curved, tube like polygon into intervals with ArcGIS Desktop 10.5.1

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, polygon, vector-grid

I am trying to divide a bunch of long, curved polygons (an example is shown in blue) into segments of 10m, from north to south, the width is 15, but is given by the lines.

My first attempt was to use a fishnet, but it didn't work and I was advised not to use the fishnet for curved polygons (see [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/442842/curved-fishnet-vector-grid-in-arcgis), I therefore decided to open a new post with more details)

Is there any tool in ArcMap 10 that would do that? I have figured out there's Subdivide (https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/subdivide-polygon.htm) and Divide Polygon (https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/editing/divide-a-polygon-by-a-value.htm)  in ArcGIS Pro, but I have not been able to find that in ArcMap 10.
Specifically, I am using ArcGIS Desktop 10.5.1.7333, License Type Advanced on a Windows 10 64 bit.

Is there any tool that would do that and preferably in an automated way (e.g. not me cutting all polygons by hand or redrawing all the polygons as parcels)? Something that inserts a perpendicular line every 10m and could be merged to a grid later?

(edited to give more specifications)

[image]

Comment: ArcMap 10 is a series of products spanning the last decade, with a great deal of difference in addressing this problem. Please [Edit] the Question to specify the **exact** software in use (e.g.. "A rcGIS 10.0 SP5 with the first sixteen security patches" or "10.8.2") , along with the license level (Advanced/Editor/Basic). It seems your first Question was an XY Problem..

Comment: Please revise your original question rather than asking a new one when that is unanswered, is clearly about the same problem and is already being looked at by the community.